# Converting the json object to string

Tags: javascript, json

I have an json object in the form

```
{
    "name" : "ok", "country" : "US","phone" : "900",
    "email" : "ok@mail.oc", "time" : "21:00"
}
```

and I want to convert it into a string which should look like the below example:

```
"{\n    \"name\": \"ok\",\n    \"country\": \"US\",\n    \"phone\": \"900\",\n    \"email\": \"ok@mail.oc\",\n    \"time\": \"21:00\",\n    \"sendData\": \"300\"\n  }"
```

I tried using JSON.stringify(); but it didn't give the desired output. Is there a easy way to achieve it. Please help me.

Comment: Which language are you using? Javascript?

Comment: Im using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve the above mentioned pattern you need to pass `JSON.stringify` into another `JSON.stringify`.

JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(data));

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to utilize something like this:
`JSON.stringify({ a: 2 }, null, ' ');`
The MDN documentation for this is located [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_space_argument). You should be able to tweak this for your desired output.

Comment: hi can you help me with this tried but im only able to get the space and able to get the \

Comment: I've tried to help you, but have no idea what you are actually try to accomplish. You will need to add more details to your question. What does that mean you are only able to get the space and the \? What else are you trying to get? How does what you are getting compare to what you want? How are you trying to use this json string?